# Suppose $X$ is normally distributed with $\mu = 3$. If $P(3 ≤ X ≤ 5) = 0.3$, what is the value of $P(X ≤ 1)$?

Tags: normal-distribution

Suppose $X$ is normally distributed with $\mu = 3$. If $P(3 ≤ X ≤ 5) = 0.3$, what is the value of $P(X ≤ 1)$?

I'm reviewing for my exam and this question comes up. I'm sorry as I don't know how to apply what formula to solve it even though I have the answer.

Comment: Recall that the normal distribution is symmetric. So  $P(X \geq 5) = P(X \geq 3) - P(3 \leq X < 5) = 1/2 - 0.3$. By the symmetry of the distribution you know the probability $X$ less than $1$ is the same as probability $X$ greater than $5$.

Comment: The key here is that $\mathbb E[X]=3$, if you do not see why $X$ should be symmetric about $3$.